# I have an existing desktop, can you move it to AWS Workspaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vdi

I have an existing desktop with a bunch of applications already installed.  Is there a way for me to move it to AWS Workspaces as is?

It seems from my testing is that AWS's Workspaces service doesn't support migrations.  You have to use their base image and then customize it with "bundles".  Is that true?

Comment: You seem to have a good grasp on the capabilities of the Workspaces offering.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/byol-windows-images.html